# Listening on multiple ports?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, netcat

Can't you listen on a port range with netcat? You can scan a range, but not listen it appears. So only solution is scripting?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/29728151/1340631

Answer (score 11):

I know this post is old, but I recently found a decent solution for this in the form of a nice one-liner.
Shell = bash, OS = Redhat 7.

```
for j in 202{0..5}; do nc -lvnp $j & done
```

This should open up a number of listening ports from 2020 to 2025, or whatever range you want.

If you are not a root user but a sudoer and have to listen to ports below 1024 add `sudo` before `nc` command.

```
for j in 101{0..5}; do sudo nc -lvnp $j & done
```

Edited : n/c: The local port parameter was missing. {-p}

Comment: Does there need to be a semicolon before the `done` statement?

Comment: @RonJohn - don't think so he's backgrounding all those invokes of `nc -lvnp $j`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it supports that functionality.  If you are happy with any old solution, you could use the `ncat` edtition of netcat, and set up forwarding for each port.  You can spawn a forwarder for all but the first port, then listen on the first port:

```
first_port=2999
last_port=3004

for (( i = first_port+1; i <= last_port; i++ )) do
    ncat -l -k -p $i -c "nc localhost $last_port" &
done

ncat -l -k -p $first_port
```

I admit, it's grungey.

Comment: Good pick for ncat vs netcat. ncat is supposed to be more secure than netcat, and is actively maintained by nmap.

Comment: And for checking is ports open `nc` can accepts range as ports.
`$ nc -zv 192.168.56.10 2999-3004`

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to scan your destination through multiple local ports, you can use the `-p <PORT>` option[1]. That tells netcat to look through that local port, much similar to when telling it to setup a backdoor listener on said port. You can also string a bunch of those ports together if they are split up. Here is an example I just used.

```
$ nc -vvz -p 80 -p 8080 -p 443 testserver.mycompany.com 3066
```

That did my trick. Of course you can also list multiple destination ports to make it scan those also through each of your local ports.

[1] http://www.instructables.com/id/More-Fun-with-netcat/step2/Basic-Netcat-commands/

Answer (score 0):

or iptables,

```
iptables -t nat -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80
```