# How to listen for multiple tcp connection using nc

Tags: linux, tcp, netcat

How to create a TCP connection using `nc` which listens to multiple hosts?

```sh
nc -l -p 12345
```

Comment: you may want to clarify whether you are looking to create multiple TCP connections **to** `nc` (e.g. from a bunch of other clients) or whether you want to listen **on** multiple TCP/IP addresses instead of listening on one and make the title and the text compliant

Comment: @HansZ. multiple tcp connection, so that multiple client connect to a single socket.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Simultaneous connections are not possible with `netcat`. You should use something like [`ucspi-tcp`](http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp.html)'s `tcpserver` tool or leverage [`xinetd`](http://www.xinetd.org/) since you're on Linux.

See: https://superuser.com/questions/232747/netcat-as-a-multithread-server

Consecutive connections could be handled through a shell script that restarts `netcat` after it finishes.

Comment: nc -k will handle incoming connections when the previous finishes, and can still accept a second connection while handling the first.

Comment: Thanks @Hans Z. .. Could you provide the example as there is no example given in that link

Comment: Author did not even ask for simultaneous connections.

Comment: @excitoon read the comments please

Comment: @HansZ. we shall answer to question, not comments

Comment: we shall read the question, the answer and the comments...

Comment: @HansZ. well if the answer is somehow related to the question, yes, otherwise we can stop early

Answer (score 22):

I recommend `socat` as `nc` alternative.

For OP's problem, `socat - TCP-LISTEN:12345,fork,reuseaddr` can do the job.

Comment: Works great! The netcat solutions require an Enter for me to print the next request.

Answer (score 20):

`ncat` can do it.

E.g. `ncat --broker --listen -p 12345` will distribute all incoming messages to all other clients (think of it as a hub).

Comment: that's pretty limited/specialized, but sure is handy to know

Comment: To clarify, `ncat -l -p 12345` does what the OP wanted. The example using `--broker` is interesting, but not relevant to this specific question.

Comment: @ToddOwen incorrect. Just tried, the second connection is always connection refused. Using --broker works.

Comment: @Ryan Would you mind trying `ncat -k -l -p 12345`? You're right, the command line I posted above does not work, but `--broker` will cause the listening process to not output anything to stdout, instead copying all data it receives back to the (other) clients, which is definitely not what the OP asked for.

Comment: @ToddOwen Unfortunately, "Ncat: UDP mode does not support the -k or --keep-open options, except with --exec or --sh-exec. QUITTING."

Comment: @Ryan It looks like you are adding `-u` to select the UDP protocol instead of the default TCP. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7696956/154770), it doesn't support that (nor does it support `--broker` with UDP). However, check out the [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53622433/154770) which I just posted.

Comment: This. is. amazing.  I've been looking for a simple tool that can do this for almost a year now.

Answer (score 15):

> -k
>       Forces nc to stay listening for another connection after its current connection is completed.  It is an error to use this option without the -l option.

Comment: Yeah, and it works exactly as requested. Once first connection is closed it will print packets from next one. Otherwise you would get a mess with data from different connections.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. With -k, netcat will accept multiple connections, but will only handle them one at a time. This was the exact answer I was looking for when I landed on this page.

Comment: I just tried this and found it (a) accepts multiple simultaneous connections, and (b) prints all the data as it is received. This is different from what some commenters above have observed, and I wonder if they were actually seeing the effects of buffering somewhere in the system?

Answer (score 4):

using `nc` it is not possible to open parallel connections to same port, however you can trick `nc` to open multiple connections to same port.

To understand this, lets say you start listening on `4444` port using `$ nc -l -p 4444 -v`. Now, if you check output of `$ netstat -anp | grep 4444` you will get its state as LISTEN and in here its pid is 3410.

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4444            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3410/nc
```

Now, after it gets connected to client, lets say you run `$ nc localhost 4444 -v`, its state will get changed into ESTABLISHED. Now, try running `$ netstat -anp | grep 4444` you will get its state as ESTABLISHED, see for same pid 3410, and a client process with pid 3435

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46678         127.0.0.1:4444          ESTABLISHED 3435/nc
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4444          127.0.0.1:46678         ESTABLISHED 3410/nc
```

Please note that there is no available listening port, so you can't have another client process. However if you run again `$ nc -l -p 4444 -v` you can have a listening port and can have multiple client process.

see `netstat -anp | grep 4444` output after you start listening to same port.

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4444            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3476/nc 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46678         127.0.0.1:4444          ESTABLISHED 3435/nc 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4444          127.0.0.1:46678         ESTABLISHED 3410/nc
```

see `netstat -anp | grep 4444` output after you attach new client to same port.

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4444          127.0.0.1:46694         ESTABLISHED 3476/nc 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46678         127.0.0.1:4444          ESTABLISHED 3435/nc 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4444          127.0.0.1:46678         ESTABLISHED 3410/nc 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46694         127.0.0.1:4444          ESTABLISHED 3483/nc
```

You can say connections behavior is like:

```
SERVER_PROCESS_1 <---> CLIENT_PROCESS_1
SERVER_PROCESS_2 <---> CLIENT_PROCESS_2
```

so, you can write some script to simulate this behavior, or use this bash script to modify.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
lport="4444"
i=0;
while [ true ]; do
    echo "opening socket $(( i++ ))";
    if [[ "$(ss sport = :$lport -l -H | wc -l)" -eq 0 ]]; then
        nc -l -vv -p $lport & 
        #do something else to process or attach different command to each diff server process
    fi;
    if [[ "$(ss sport = :$lport -l -H | wc -l)" -ne 0 ]]; then
        watch -n 0.1 -g "ss sport = :$lport -l -H" > /dev/null;
    fi;
    if [[ i -eq 10 ]]; then
        break;
    fi;
done;
```

in here every time client consume a connection this script will start new listen socket.

This behavior is however can be changed in `ncat` (here, using `-k`)as you can analyze the with below example:

server is started using `$ ncat -l -p 4444 -v -4 -k` and 3 clients are started using `$ ncat -4 localhost 4444`. Now output for `$ netstat -anp | grep 4444` is:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4444            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3596/ncat
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4444          127.0.0.1:46726         ESTABLISHED 3596/ncat
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46726         127.0.0.1:4444          ESTABLISHED 3602/ncat
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46722         127.0.0.1:4444          ESTABLISHED 3597/ncat
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4444          127.0.0.1:46724         ESTABLISHED 3596/ncat
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4444          127.0.0.1:46722         ESTABLISHED 3596/ncat
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46724         127.0.0.1:4444          ESTABLISHED 3601/ncat
```

Every time new client connect, server fork its process to attach to client, so each server process is using same pid. So output of server in this way is shared to every attached clients, however each client can send individual message to server.

You can say connections behavior is like:

```
SERVER_PROCESS_1 <---> CLIENT_PROCESS_1
SERVER_PROCESS_1 <---> CLIENT_PROCESS_2
SERVER_PROCESS_1 <---> CLIENT_PROCESS_3
```

without `-k`, `ncat` will behave same as `nc`.

Benefits or loses can be defined on how they are to be needed.

For this example, i used `nc` or `nc.traditional` (v1.10-41.1+b1), and `ncat` (7.80).

Answer (score 1):

`ncat` can do it, but the correct command with ncat is:

`ncat --keep-open --listen -p 12345`

This will accept multiple connections at the same time.

You can then send the data with multiple clients.  e.g. open in two or more terminals, and try typing there:

`nc localhost 12345`

Answer (score 0):

This is an incomplete answer, because I haven't got it working. Arguably more of a question, in fact. Maybe someone else can finish it off.

First of all, it seems there are different versions of netcat. I'm on Ubuntu, so I've probably got the version that came with Ubuntu. When I `nc -h`, it says this:

```
OpenBSD netcat (Debian patchlevel 1.187-1ubuntu0.1)
```

When I run `man nc`, it says this:

```
-F      Pass the first connected socket using sendmsg(2) to stdout and exit.  This
        is useful in conjunction with -X to have nc perform connection setup with
        a proxy but then leave the rest of the connection to another program (e.g.
        ssh(1) using the ssh_config(5) ProxyUseFdpass option).
```

It seems to me that this means that, instead of doing the usual thing with stdin and stdout, it just prints something to stdout. That something could then be used by another process to do the actual connection to the client.

Unfortunately, `-F` has no effect that I can see. So maybe I'm doing it wrong. Or maybe there's some secret pipe somewhere that I have to listen to, or a supplementary argument they forgot to document. Or maybe I happen to have a broken build of netcat, and it works for everyone else who's on Ubuntu.

In combination with the `-k` option (or, failing that, a while-true loop), this would allow many different clients to have separate connections. Suppose you have an executable called `handle_connection`, which takes as arguments an in file descriptor from a client and an out file descriptor to the client, and spawns a subprocess which communicates with the client. Then the server script might look like this:

```
nc -lkF $host $port | while read in out ; do
    handle_connection $in $out ;
done
```