# How can I communicate with a unix socket using one connection in a bash script?

Tags: bash, unix-socket

I want to read/write to a unix socket in a bash script, but only do it with one connection. All of the examples I've seen using nc say to open different socket connections for every read/write.

Is there a way to do it using one connection throughout the script for every read/write?

(nc only lets me communicate with the socket in a one shot manner)

Answer (score 0):

Run the whole script with output redirected:

```
{
    command
    command
    command
} | nc -U /tmp/cppLLRBT-socket
```

However, pipes are one-way, so you can do this for reading or writing, but not both.

Comment: I can't... 

[aa@localhost cppB-tree]$ ls -l /tmp/cppLLRBT-socket 
srwxrwxr-x. 1 aa aa 0 Oct 26 19:20 /tmp/cppLLRBT-socket
[aa@localhost cppB-tree]$ exec 3<>/tmp/cppLLRBT-socket 
bash: /tmp/cppLLRBT-socket: No such device or address

It refuses to work for some reason

Comment: Sockets aren't accessed using the normal file `open()` function. How are you doing it for each read/write now?

Comment: echo "blaa" | nc -U /tmp/cppLLRBT-socket

Comment: Is there way to do this bi-directionally over a Unix domain socket while being able to distinguish between the processes writing to it?

Comment: @Melab Open separate connections for each client process.

Comment: I don't follow. I thought two different client processes necessarily implies two separate connections. Even if you do that, how would the server process tell which message sent over the socket is from which client process?

Comment: @Melab I'm not really an expert on using netcat, but maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728151/how-to-listen-for-multiple-tcp-connection-using-nc) will help you.