# open a port permanently on linux using nc (netcat)

Tags: linux, bash, docker, networking, netcat

This topic is mentioned multiple times everywhere but none of the solutions work for me.

I have multiple Linux host machines, they are actually docker containers, based on `alpine` image. I would like to open a port on `host-a` permanently in a background process once the host (container) is up and ready. This signal informs other machines that the `host-a` is ready to do something.

Parallelly `host-b` and `host-c` are checking in bash loops that remote port and waiting for this signal, then continuing.

I use `nc` command to open the port permanently in the background and I use `nc` to check whether the remote port is opened or not. But unfortunately, my solution does not work and if it works then it is unstable, and exists after the first check.

**host-a: open the port permanently in the background**

```
nc -lk -v -p "$UP_SIGNAL_PORT" &
next-command-in-my-script...
```

**This is how `host-b` and `host-c` check the port status:**

```
while ! nc -w 5 -z "$domain" "$UP_SIGNAL_PORT" 2>/dev/null; do
  sleep 0.5
done
continue...
```

It seems that the command that opens the port exists after the first "ping".

I have also tried the following command but it behaves strangely:

```
[host-a]# nc -lk -p 12345 &
[host-a]# ps axu
1114 root      0:00 nc -lk -p 12345

[host-b]# nc -zv hello.com 12345
hello.com (172.19.0.2:12345) open

try to check the port again
[host-b]# nc -zv hello.com 12345
NO result


[host-a]# ps axu
1114 root      0:00 nc -lk -p 12345
the process is still running BUT the port seems to be closed
```

after the first remote "ping"

What is wrong here?

**The `nc` version that I have:**

```
# nc
BusyBox v1.35.0 (2022-11-19 10:13:10 UTC) multi-call binary.
```

**--- UPDATE ---**

As per your suggestion, I tried this, but unfortunately did not work:

```
[host-a]# yes hello | nc -lk -v -p 12345 >/dev/null &
[1] 1125
[root@host-a.hello.com]# listening on [::]:12345 ...

[root@host-a.hello.com]# connect to [::ffff:172.19.0.2]:12345 from host-b.hello.com.docker_default:40841 ([::ffff:172.19.0.3]:40841)
nc: too many output retries

[1]+  Exit 1                  yes hello | nc -lk -v -p 12345 > /dev/null
```

**host-b:**

```
[root@host-b.hello.com]# nc -zv host-a.hello.com 12345
host-a.hello.com (172.19.0.2:12345) open
[root@host-b.hello.com]# nc -zv host-a.hello.com 12345
no answer after the 1st ping
```

Unfortunately, this exists also after the first ping.

Comment: Try `xinetd` it's better for your task.

Comment: `nc` is the wrong tool for this job (to a greater or lesser degree based on which version you have; the more appropriate ones have the option to fork a subprocess for each new incoming connection). Use a proper built-to-purpose superserver -- xinetd was the up-and-coming standard 25 years ago; today I'd suggest [`tcpsvd`](http://smarden.org/ipsvd/tcpsvd.8.html). (In some cases a systemd socket unit is appropriate, but I'm not sure you're in one of those cases).

Comment: You tagged this with "docker".  In a Docker context, you should run `nc` (or the real server process) as a foreground process as the image's `CMD`, as the only thing running in its container; you should not normally need interactive shells in containers, nor should you need to manually launch a server in a container after it's started.

Comment: Relevant: [Minimal webserver using netcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640054/minimal-web-server-using-netcat), [How to listen for multiple connections using nc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728151/how-to-listen-for-multiple-tcp-connection-using-nc)

Comment: See the `socat` answer there -- in particular, instead of using `-`/stdin on the side opposite the listen socket, you can tell socat to fork off an arbitrary executable, so you can have a script of your choice started for each incoming connection, to listen to the request and send an appropriate response.

Comment: Actually, I do not have/need any response. The only one that "clients" check is whether the port is opened or not. There is no request and response body in my case. I use this as a true/false variable. It the port is opened, then continue, if not, wait and check the port status after 500 ms.

Comment: Hm. You may actually be _in_ a place where a systemd socket unit is the right thing, then. (Socket activation -- like the work of any other superserver -- has systemd itself keep a socket open, and then spawn a child process, passing it a pre-opened file descriptor, when there's actually traffic on the port; so you don't have the memory of running a separate process, even a trivial one like `nc`, except when there are actually connecting clients; and systemd keeps the port open no matter whether the program to handle an incoming connection is running or not).

Comment: But then `systemd` inside Docker tends to be somewhere between pesky and impossible. (Or, well, maybe things have improved since last time I looked.)

Comment: `nc`-in-a-loop, though, is _never_ the right thing (as there's no listen socket as it circles back around to the top between invocations), and `nc` without a loop is... hard to predict enough to write good answers around it. There are at least three different commonly-distributed, independently-developed programs under the "netcat" name (one from the GNU project, one from nmap's authors, one from the BSD world), they're all a little different, and none of them are built with the immediate use case in mind.

Comment: @tripleee, agreed, in Docker I'd stick with tcpsvd, or just write a tiny server in Python/Go/Rust/C/whatnot.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The `socat` is a really cool tool. I was able to open a port permanently with this tool using the `socat - tcp-listen:"$UP_SIGNAL_PORT",fork,reuseaddr &` command. I only neded to modify this part in my code. The port check remained untouched. If you add this as a solution then I will accept it.

Answer (score -2):

Wrap it in a function and start it in background:

```
fun(){
    nc -lk -v -p "$UP_SIGNAL_PORT"
    fun
}

fun &
```

Or use `xinetd`

Comment: Too much recursion will eventually blow the stack.

Comment: It depends how often it would be pinged. Recursion happens on nc close.

Comment: Right, but starting up a server that's going to die after some number of connections, be it 5,000 or 16,384, is not what someone saying they want to open a port "permanently" is asking for.

Comment: Right, tell this to k8s developers)